# Load image data from WPS response using OL

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wps

We have a React application using OpenLayers and Geoserver.

We have a countrywide raster layer in Geoserver and want to load a cropped version in OL when a province is selected.

We have the WPS part working, it is returning the cropped data.
We also get the data as base64 back in OL and set it as the source of the layer, but nothing is shown on the map. It seems like the layer isn't updated.

```js
const tempUrl =
    "http://localhost:8480/geoserver/ows?service=WPS&version=1.0.0";
var wpsLayer = new ImageLayer({
    source: new ImageWMS({
      url:
        "http://localhost:8480/geoserver/umva_geo/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=Aarea0&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=658&HEIGHT=769",
      imageLoadFunction: function (image, src) {
        console.log("fetching");
        var img = image.getImage();
        fetch(tempUrl, {
          method: "POST",
          body: xmlWps,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/xml",
            Accept: "image/jpeg",
          },
        })
          .then((data) => data.blob())
          .then((data) => {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(data);
            reader.onload = function () {
              var base64data = reader.result;
              img.src = base64data;
              console.log('source is changed');
            };
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      },
    }),
  });
```

Of course, the layer is added to the map.

We've tried several days understanding why it is not working, please advice.

**Edit**:
After the suggestion of @Mike we changed from requesting a tiff to a png. That didn't work we got this error: `An error occurred while encoding the results of the process No suitable image writer for this output.`
Changing to jpeg did work, but then we loose the transparency. But for testing this is OK.
But when setting the img.src to the base64 response we did see the jpeg image appear on the map. But only briefly, too small and at the wrong location.
This makes sense because the JPEG file doesn't contain any geospatial data like coordinates. So how would OL know where to place the image.
Perhaps we need a different layer/source than ImageLayer/ImageWMS?

Comment: Are you requesting tiff format?  Most web browsers do not handle that.

Comment: @MikeYes we request tiff format. Perhaps that is the problem? I'll see if I can request it as png

Comment: Hi @Mike Using the WPS Request Builder we change the generate option from tiff to png, but now we get this error `An error occurred while encoding the results of the process No suitable image writer for this output.` We can't figure out what is the problem. Our WMS services are successfully generating PNG tiles. We had a look at installing the native JAI and ImageIO but then Geoserver won't start anymore.